# React Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I tried to create a login page and that's the error I get anytime I try to login. I tried to solve it but I didn't find any solution.

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at login.component.js:136)
    in div (at login.component.js:135)
    in form (created by t)
    in t (created by Form(t))
    in Form(t) (at login.component.js:92)
    in div (at login.component.js:85)
    in div (at login.component.js:84)
    in Login (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:140)
    in Switch (at App.js:131)
    in div (at App.js:130)
    in div (at App.js:52)
    in App (at src/index.js:10)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:9)
```

Register and other pages work fine for me, so I wonder what I messed up with login.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zvCjzJag it's the code of login.component.js

Comment: Well looks like you're trying to render an object as a react component... We won't be able to help you much further than that without seeing the code that caused this issue. Try to make a small re-producable example and share it here

Comment: Show your code here in your question, please.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LCD2J7GV  -  App.js

Comment: @Aza can you please edit your question an include it here and not off-site

Comment: A link to your code is not your code. Also, _in your question_.

Comment: I wanted to put more of the code in the question but the problem is that i was getting an error which said that i was using too much code.

Answer (score 0):

You try to render an Object. Try `Object.values(myObj)`